# Maintaining order in MySQL "IN" query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`foo`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`foo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I try to get records based on the primary key

```
SELECT * FROM foo f where f.id IN (2, 3, 1);
```

I then get the following result

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | first  |
|  2 | second |
|  3 | third  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As one can see, the result is ordered by id. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the results ordered in the sequence I'm providing in the query. Given this example it should return

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | second |
|  3 | third  |
|  1 | first  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Check this answer on the MySQL site: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,210905,210918#msg-210918 -- I think you're going to run into trouble expecting in() to behave like this. MySQL doesn't really sort the results unless you explicitly tell it to, and you don't have anything in the data that will sort it the way you want.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As the other answer mentions: the query you posted has nothing about what order you'd like your results, just which results you'd like to get.

To order your results, I would use `ORDER BY FIELD()`:

```
SELECT * FROM foo f where f.id IN (2, 3, 1)
ORDER BY FIELD(f.id, 2, 3, 1);
```

The argument list to [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) can be variable length.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if either method has a performance advantage in the general case of ordering rows by ID.  I've always used FIELD() but I've seen a few examples of code that uses the FIND_IN_SET() method you posted.

Comment: Is there an alternative for this in DB2?

Answer (score 29):

The values in an `IN()` predicate are considered to be a set, and the result returned by an SQL query has no way to automatically infer order from that set.

In general, the order of any SQL query is arbitrary *unless* you specify an order with an `ORDER BY` clause.

You can use a MySQL function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM foo f where f.id IN (2, 3, 1)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(f.id, '2,3,1');
```

Note that the list argument to `FIND_IN_SET()` isn't a variable length list like the arguments of `IN()`.  It has to be a string literal or a [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html).

---

Re questions about performance:  I'm curious too, so I tried both `FIND_IN_SET()` and [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) methods against my copy of the StackOverflow data:

With no index on VoteTypeId:

```
SELECT * FROM Votes ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(VoteTypeId, '13,1,12,2,11,3,10,4,9,5,8,6,7');

3618992 rows in set (31.26 sec)
3618992 rows in set (29.67 sec)
3618992 rows in set (28.52 sec)

SELECT * FROM Votes ORDER BY FIELD(VoteTypeId, 13,1,12,2,11,3,10,4,9,5,8,6,7);

3618992 rows in set (37.30 sec)
3618992 rows in set (49.65 sec)
3618992 rows in set (41.69 sec)
```

With an index on VoteTypeId:

```
SELECT * FROM Votes ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(VoteTypeId, '13,1,12,2,11,3,10,4,9,5,8,6,7');

3618992 rows in set (14.71 sec)
3618992 rows in set (14.81 sec)
3618992 rows in set (25.80 sec)

SELECT * FROM Votes ORDER BY FIELD(VoteTypeId, 13,1,12,2,11,3,10,4,9,5,8,6,7);

3618992 rows in set (19.03 sec)
3618992 rows in set (14.59 sec)
3618992 rows in set (14.43 sec)
```

Conclusion: with limited testing, there is no great advantage to either method.

Comment: much nicer that CASE 'x' THEN 1, CASE 'y' THEN 2 for an arbitrary order column

Comment: thanks for clarifying that one - i went for the other answer as FIELD with variable arguments seems more intuitive for me. but i'd also be interested in a performance comparison.

Comment: yeah didn't think there'd be much if any difference, but thanks for the test results :)

Comment: interesting. so there isn't a great advantage if there's an index on VoteTypeId - without an index however FIND_IN_SET seems to be the better option ... thanks for the testing!

Comment: I'll add the disclaimer that I ran these tests on a Macbook with only 2GB RAM, and perhaps without adequate memory cooldown in between tests.  So my margin of error might be a bit high.  :-)