# Working with Eloquent, How to select popular comments

Tags: laravel

I am designer trying to learn coding here and Laravel is so great in that it enables design like me to be able to create something myself smile

On to my question, I followed some of tutorial and now I learn to build simple blog system. 
So I have Post model that has relationship `$this->morphMany('Like','likeable','likeable_type');` with Like model.
Everything works great so far. Now I want to be able to create 'Popular Posts' page that basically shows the posts ordered by popularity, which is number of likes in my case.

The 'likes' table has these field `id | likable_id | likeable_type`

- 'likeable_type', in this case, is 'Post'
- 'likeable_id' is the post id linked to id in 'posts' table

So in my controller, I tried this.

```
$popular_ids = DB::table('likes')
                  ->select('likeable_id')
                  ->groupBy('likeable_id')
                  ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(likeable_id)'), 'DESC')
                  ->get();
$popular_posts = Post::whereIn('id',array_pluck($popular_ids,'likeable_id'))->paginate(15);
```

This gives me all the popular posts but not in the order that I want.
I'm not sure if there is better way to achieve this or it seems that I only miss another 'orderBy' method?

Any suggestion on this?

ps. Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

SQL IN does not maintain order. To achieve this have to user ORDER BY FIELD('id', , ,...) to achieve this.

```
$ids = array_pluck($popular_ids,'likeable_id');
$raw = DB::raw('FIELD(id,' + implode(',', $ids) + ')');

$popular_posts = Post::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderBy($raw)->paginate(15);
```

For more information refer to,

[Maintaining order in MySQL "IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631723/maintaining-order-in-mysql-in-query)

Comment: Thank you for your time to share your answer Tharanga. I never heard of FIELD before! I learn something new today. I modified code from Collin's answer and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a join. It's kinda complex but if you want to understand the internals you should read into LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN. This example is particularly ugly because of the polymorphic relationship.

```
Post::select('posts.*', DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT likes.id) AS popularity'))
    ->leftJoin('likes', function ($join)
    {
        $join->on('likes.likeable_id', '=', 'posts.id')
            ->on('likes.likeable_type', '=', DB::raw("'Post'"));
    })
    ->orderBy('popularity', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(15);
```

There is a bonus in that the popularity value is now available on the posts.

```
$post->popularity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Collin for your time! Your answer leads me to the light!!! I modified your answer a bit and finally get what I need. I'm still trying to fully understand it though. This is what I ended up with.

```
Post::select('posts.*', DB::raw('COUNT(likes.likeable_id) AS popularity'))
   ->join('likes', function($join)
   {
      $join->on('likes.likeable_id', '=', 'posts.id')
           ->on('likes.likeable_type', '=', DB::raw("'Post'")); 
   })
   ->groupBy('likes.likeable_id')
   ->orderBy('popularity', 'DESC')
   ->paginate(15);
```

Ps. Even though this code gives me what I want, I'm not sure if I did my db design right.