# Is there a way to perform a MySQL query that accepts an array of values and only returns results of the first value found?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to run a single query that accepts an array of values to search on and goes one by one until there are results found.

Basically I want to take this sort of setup and put it in a single query:

```
$arr_vals = [ array of values here ];

foreach( $arr_vals as $arr_val ){
    $results = mysql_query( SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE some_field = $arr_val );
    if( mysql_num_rows( $results ) ){
        return $results;
    }
}
```

So, if there is any way to not run multiple queries and return only results for the current value. I'd rather not limit and I'd rather not filter results with PHP after because the result count could be high.

Thanks.

EDIT!!!

I don't want just a 'single' match here. I want results from the first matched value which could be 1 row or 1000 rows... a LIMIT could be put in place later, but I don't want that to be the crutch of the answer... obviously this is a simple answer if the LIMIT is 1... then I'd just use IN().

Comment: `WHERE field IN ()`

Comment: What have you tried? How on earth do people still use mysql? You don't concat array to string by the way..

Comment: I'll add the query... this is not my actual code, just a snippet... you should get the gist of what I mean there

Comment: not sure really.. Anyway, if you are trying to pass an array of ids, use `IN()` as @u_mulder suggested, but after concating them as a string obviously.

Comment: And also do mention on what order you want to search, as you want to get the first match.

Comment: and also do make a query to get result lol :P

Comment: **One idea:** With PDO, you could have a bunch of SELECTs separated by `;` one after the other, then you'd call `nextRowset` to get the results of each select. Is that worth, though?

Comment: Alright. Now we are at the point ath which some sample data and expected output would be great. Also the WHOLE question, not new information after every comment.,,

Comment: I didn't add any new info, just made it more clear. I stated in the original question "I'd rather not limit and I'd rather not filter results with PHP." People are assuming that a single row is acceptable but I never stated that. Thanks.

Comment: @FirstOne that would go against the whole reason to try and perform a single query. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an array of values to use as criteria, but each value may match many rows, and you want only the matches of the first value that matches, but you want all the rows that match. So LIMIT is totally not going to do what you want.

Assuming PHP variable `$values` is a comma-separated list of integers, so these values are safe to interpolate (not going to create an SQL injection vulnerability):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM MyTable AS t
JOIN (
  SELECT someField
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE someField IN ($values)
  ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(someField, '$values')
  LIMIT 1
) AS first ON (t.someField = first.someField);
```

If the values are not integers, you'll have to make two PHP variables, one where each value is quoted individually, and the other where they are a single string, not quoted.

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/641bd/2)

Comment: This is great except one small detail... it continues through all values and orders by first that would have been found. This might be workable.

Comment: Basically if your array was 1,2,3,4,5 and 3,4,5 were all found results it would always give you the 3 row even if your array was 5,4,3,2,1. My intended result is to always give back the first found which in the 2nd array should be 5. If the array was 4,1,2,3,5 it should give me 4 back.

Comment: Read up on how MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function works, and read the answers to [Maintaining order in MySQL “IN” query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631723/)

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD() is what's needed instead of ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: Either function works equally well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
$arr_str = implode (", ", $arr);

select * from my_db where unq_col = (SELECT unq_col FROM my_db WHERE some_field in ($arr_str) limit 1)
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score -1):

$query="SELECT * FROM  table_name where some_field in ('".implode(',', $arr_vals)."')";

Comment: Nope, doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: Use break statement after first match found in for loop

Comment: He wants to do it in a single query

Comment: Use case-when-then-else statement in the query