# SQL, "WHERE IN" returns automatically sorted result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

When I run my query with an `WHERE IN` statement, it seems like it automaticly sorts the product_id that are returned.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM PIM WHERE product_id in (10,8,1,3)";

foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo $row['product_id'] . "<br>";
}
```

Result:

```
1
3
8
10
```

I want them returned in the order they entered in (10,8,1,3)

Comment: It may by chance return them in that order; but unless you specify an ORDER BY clause, then the return order is indeterminate (`ORDER BY FIELD(product_id, 10, 8, 1, 3)`)

Comment: If you want your SQL results in a specific order, you will have to add a specific `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: [*"A common question on the mailing lists is how to sort results in a particular order. Just use the FIELD function:"*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in your original query you did not specify which order MySQL should use then is using ASC, Try using ORDER BY FIELD() like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PIM WHERE product_id in (10,8,1,3) ORDER BY FIELD(product_id, 10,8,1,3);
```

Check this [great answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631749/1016425).

Comment: Thanks, that worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select * from PIM where id in (1,3,8,10) order by find_in_set(id,'10,8,1,3');
```