# How can i convert an array to an rails ActiveRecord::Relation without changing array order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have number of restaurants. On the fly i sorted out restaurants and stored to an array. Later I converted this array to rails object. When I did this array sorted order gone. How can I keep array order while converting to an rails object?

**Edit:-**

```
@restaurants = [res1,res2,res3,res4,res5]
sorted_array = [res1,res5,res2,res4,res3]
@places =Restaurant.where(:id=> sorted_array.map(:&id))
```

then i got below order of rails objects

```
@places = [res1,res2,res3,res4,res5]
```

I want to order like below when I convert an array to a rails object.

How can I get same order as an array ?

```
@places = [res1,res5,res2,res4,res3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want (`res1 ... res5` should be `Restaurant` objects)

```
ids = [res1,res5,res2,res4,res3].map(&:id)
@places = Restaurant.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})").all
```

More info, [Maintaining order in MySQL "IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631723/maintaining-order-in-mysql-in-query)

Comment: This is answer i want, near to me. By the way what's FIELD here ?. when i run this code snipped it returning empty  object like below with all ids in same order    <Restaurant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2b24d9a37b58>. How can i get restaurants from this?

Comment: @MaheshBabu Please show what `Restaurant.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})").to_sql` says. FIELDS -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally

Comment: Hey, i got below one  "SELECT `restaurants`.* FROM `restaurants` WHERE `restaurants`.`id` IN (597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 828, 1030, 1174, 1299, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2426, 2511, 2704, 2906, 2907, 2948, 3581, 3610, 3716)  ORDER BY FIELD(id,597,598,599,600,601,602,603,828,1030,1174,1299,2310,2311,2312,2313,2314,2315,2316,2317,2318,2320,2321,2322,2323,2426,2511,2704,2906,2907,2948,3581,3610,3716"

Comment: @MaheshBabu But those ids are already sorted ASC. No need for FIELDS. `Restaurant.where(id: ids).all` should give you an array of Restaurant objects.  Btw, you are missing a `)` at the end of ORDER BY

Comment: Restaurant.where(id: ids).all   is not giving sorted array order restaurants.

Comment: @MaheshBabu Then this will `Restaurant.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})").all`

Comment: Restaurant.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})").all it's working perfectly. thank you.

Comment: @MaheshBabu Great. Please don't forget to mark as answered.

Comment: It won't work on a collection with more than 100 instances

Answer (score 0):

Is that sorted array an array of Restaurant records? Curious because you're 
trying to call `#id` on the map block. Where are `res1`-`res5` defined?

Another thing to note is your `&` syntax looks off, I think you need to say `sorted_array.map(&:id)`, otherwise it's trying to call `#&id` on each restaurant record.

If it's a small array length like 5, in this case, you could map from the sorted array:

`@places = sorted_array.map { |restaurant| Restaurant.find(restaurant.id) }`

Comment: It's good idea, suppose if i have 100 restaurants then will it be good?

Comment: 100 is pretty high, but you might be able to get away with it. Try it out!

Where are res1-res5 defined?

Comment: Restaurant.all = [res1-res5]