# Maintaining order in DB2 "IN" query

Tags: db2

This question is based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631794/1965453). I'm looking for a solution to that question that works in DB2. Here is the original question:

I have the following table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`foo`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`foo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I try to get records based on the primary key

```
SELECT * FROM foo f where f.id IN (2, 3, 1);
```

I then get the following result

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | first  |
|  2 | second |
|  3 | third  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As one can see, the result is ordered by id. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the results ordered in the sequence I'm providing in the query. Given this example it should return

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | second |
|  3 | third  |
|  1 | first  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The `IN` list doesn't have an order (in a proper SQL database anyway). However, it's not exactly clear what order you want, and why.

Comment: I changed my question to be identical to the question I referenced. I'm really just looking for the same answer to that question but for db2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a derived table with the IDs you want, and the order you want, and then join the table in, something like...

```
SELECT ...
FROM   mcscb.mcs_premise prem
JOIN   mcscb.mcs_serv_deliv_id serv 
  ON   prem.prem_nb = serv.prem_nb 
 AND   prem.tech_col_user_id = serv.tech_col_user_id 
 AND   prem.tech_col_version = serv.tech_col_version 
JOIN (
    SELECT 1, '9486154876' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '9403149581' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '9465828230' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
) B (ORD, ID)
ON    serv.serv_deliv_id = B.ID
WHERE serv.tech_col_user_id = 'CRSSJEFF' 
  AND serv.tech_col_version = '00'
ORDER BY B.ORD
```

Comment: I've changed my question to be identical to the question I'm referencing.

Comment: @AlexM you changed your wording, but the answer is still the same. SQL does not have a definite order. If you want an order, you have to use `ORDER BY`, and to use that, you have to *give* something to order on... And in this case to do that, you will have to correlate the order you want with the ID (you can't just pass in a list and expect SQL to keep the same order, the database can freely re-order your list in a way that best makes sense to it). Which is what my answer does.

Comment: Thank you for not just answering my question but refactoring my query!

Answer (score 1):

You can use derived column to do custom ordering.

`select
case 
when serv.SERV_DELIV_ID = '9486154876' then 1 ELSE
when serv.SERV_DELIV_ID = '9403149581' then 2 ELSE 3 
END END as custom_order,
...
...
ORDER BY custom_order`

Comment: I've changed my question to be identical to the question I'm referencing.

Answer (score 1):

To make the logic a little bit more evident you might modify the [solution provided by bhamby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559549/1227152) like so:

```
WITH ordered_in_list (ord, id) as (
  VALUES (1, '9486154876'), (2, '9403149581'), (3, '9465828230')
)
SELECT ...
FROM   mcscb.mcs_premise prem
JOIN   mcscb.mcs_serv_deliv_id serv 
  ON   prem.prem_nb = serv.prem_nb 
 AND   prem.tech_col_user_id = serv.tech_col_user_id 
 AND   prem.tech_col_version = serv.tech_col_version 
JOIN   ordered_in_list il 
  ON   serv.serv_deliv_id = il.ID
WHERE serv.tech_col_user_id = 'CRSSJEFF' 
  AND serv.tech_col_version = '00'
ORDER BY il.ORD
```

Comment: When I tried this I received the error `ILLEGAL SYMBOL "ORDERED_IN_LIST". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: DSN_INLINE_OPT_HINT. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.15.100 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601`

Comment: What's your Db2 version/platform? You should have stated that in your question.

Comment: @AlexM db2 for z/os doesn't allow such a usage of VALUES. Must be: `WITH ordered_in_list (ord, id) as (
          select 1, '9486154876' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select 2, '9403149581' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select 3, '9465828230' from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select ...`