# Return mySQL results in the order they're called in an IN() statement

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can return a set of mySQL rows in the order they're called. For instance, when I call this:

```
SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE id IN ( 41 , 48 , 38 , 14 , 47 , 44 ) LIMIT 6
```

I'd like the rows returned in that order. Is there a php function I could apply to the results afterward to achieve this ordering?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, take a look at ["Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause) answers.
The solution is very well described there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 41, 48, 38, 14, 47, 44) ASC`.

EDIT: Found a better function than `FIND_IN_SET`.