# With a SELECT...WHERE id IN (...), order results by IN()?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

With a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE id IN (12,9,15,3,1)
```

is it possible to order the results by the contents of the IN clause?

The result I'm looking for would be something like:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [file_name] => foo
    )   
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [file_name] => bar
    )   
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [file_name] => baz
    )
...
```

Comment: Very interesting question, I've wondered too.

Comment: This might be a nice question but it is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `IN` clause defines a set, and a set in mathematics has no order.

However there seems to be a workaround for MySQL by using the [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

- [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause/396771#396771)

Comment: Yes it is possible by tweaking the SQL query. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for the tip. Modified my answer to make it more accurate.