# PrestoDB - Order results by the order specified in the WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, presto

I saw in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435986/with-a-select-where-id-in-order-results-by-in) that we can do this with the [FIELD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in MySQL. I am wondering if there is an equivalent of FIELD() in presto. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `in`.  I would recommend `join` with `values`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (values (1, 'val1'), (2, 'val2'), (3, 'val3')) v(ord, val)
     on t.col = v.val
order by v.ord;
```