# SQL IN statement and ordering the results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a comma delimited list of ids that I want to use to retrieve records from the database. I can use the IN statement to get the results but I want the order of the results to be the same order as the original list.

EG

```
$list = "3,1,4,2,5";
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (" . $list . ")";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo($row['id']. ", " ); // returns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
}
```

OK so I get the results back in the order that they appear in the database - fair enough but I want the results to be in the same order as the original list, I want SQL to retrieve 3 first, then 1 etc...

Is there a SQL command to do this or do I just need to arrange the result the way I need it by some array shuffling? What is the best way to do this?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (" . $list . ") ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '".$list."')";
```