# MySQL WHERE IN - Ordering

Tags: sql, mysql, database

When using:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN(4,2,1,3,5);
```

The resulting order is:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

What can I do to return the results in the same order I queried them in?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE id IN(4,2,1,3,5)
ORDER BY FIELD (id, 4,2,1,3,5);
```

More info on [`MySQL FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table 
WHERE id IN (4,2,1,3,5)
order by case id
    when 4 then 1
    when 2 then 2
    when 1 then 3
    when 3 then 4
    when 5 then 5
end
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 4
union all
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 2
union all
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 1
union all
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 3
union all
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 5
```