# mySQL: Can one rely on the implicit ORDER BY done by mySQL when using an IN-Statement?

Tags: mysql, database

I just noticed that,
when i execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE some_key = 1 AND some_foreign_key IN (2,5,23,8,9);
```

the results come back in the same order they where given in the IN-Statement List,
e.g. the row with **some_foreign_key** = 2 is the first row returned, 
the one with
**some_foreign_key** = 9 is the last and so on.

This is exactly the opposite behaviour of what this guy describes:

[MySQL WHERE IN - Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609986/mysql-where-in-ordering)

Can one rely on this behaviour or modify it via some mySQL Server setting?

I know common wisdom is "no ORDER BY Clause" == "RDBMS can sort however it pleases",
but in my current Task at hand this behaviour is quite helpful (really large import)
and it would be great if i could rely on it.

EDIT: I know about the **ORDER BY FIELD** Trick already, just wanted to know if i can safely avoid the ORDER BY Clause by setting some config somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY FIELD(some_foreign_key, 2, 5, 23, 8, 9)

isn't really that tough to implement - unless you're really simplifying this example. And as you already know it's the only way to be 100% sure of the output ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already know about the **FIELD** function, i just wanted to know if this "default sorting behaviour" (for lack of a better term) can be configured somewhere to avoid the ORDER BY FIELD altogether. Dealing with lots of data and PHP here, which means i use some Hacks from time to time to get this particular script as fast as i possibly can :-)

Comment: And yes my example is really simplified. That select is executed quite often.