# Yet another QuerySet custom ordering problem

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Lots of searching, found nothing so far.

In my django app, Model_X is rated by my users using a very standard ratings model.  I have a standalone function that processes a LOT of data and when given a user instance, returns a list of tuples.  The first value corresponds to the primary key for an instance of Model_X, and the second is the predicted rating.  For example, it might return the following list of tuples.

```
[(1L, 5.25), (5L, 3.1), (23L, 1.83)]
```

I need to return a QuerySet (and it needs to be a QuerySet) of Model_X, containing only the instances listed in the tuples, sorted by these predicted ratings from the tuples.

Comment: I know that I can do this using the python sorted() function but I need this to return a QuerySet which to my understanding cannot be done with the sorted() function.

Comment: Can you add some code which explains you models. I don't get exactly what your example is representing. Field values from one model and its instances or from different models combined instances?

Comment: I've reworded my question with hopes of making it a bit clearer.  Does this help?  The field values on the model don't come into play at all in this process.

Comment: do you really need to return a QuerySet?

Comment: I have a O(n) solution in mind, where you are are chaining lookups using the values in the list to maintain order... But hopefully someone comes by with a better solution.

Comment: I'll take the O(n) solution over the fat NOTHING I have right now.

Comment: @vad My app has a very intensive view that renders 4 different models, sorts, filters, searches, paginates, etc and it is built on the back of being able to use the order_by method.  I have already begun brainstorming how this will need to be changed if I can't get a solution to this problem, but for now I'm holding onto hope.

Comment: @Aaron: but if you sort using reputation, then you can't order_by. Better: you can, but it's not so good ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your list of rating tuples is already ordered you might be able to use something from [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause).

If you're using MySQL then the `field()` function should work for you.  Pull all the ids from your sorted rating tuples, `[x[0] for x in sorted_tuples]` and then use that list of ids to build your where clause, e.g. (untested),

```
Model_X.objects.raw('select * from myapp_model_x where id in (5,1,23) order by field(id,5,1,23)'])
```

Comment: I may be doing this wrong, but using your syntax it spits out an error starting at the 'order by field...' statement inside the where statement.

Comment: ah, that's unfortunate.  You may have to drop down to a [raw query](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) to run that properly.  Are you using MySQL?

Comment: I'm going to just resort to my alternative which is to use python's sorted and rewrite my view.  I can't believe that this can't be done.  Seems like a major shortfall that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list instead of a QuerySet. You can easily build it using [in_bulk](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk)

Comment: Been very specific in multiple places that I am looking for a solution that returns a QuerySet.