# SQL Ordering in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL select statment and want to make this into one query.

```
 select * from users where...
```

The where clause will have four parts, and they need to be ordered this way:

```
 1. where description = "query"

 2. where description = "%query%"

 3. where description = "q1" or description = "q2"

 4. where description = "%q1%" or description = "%q2%"
```

Comment: Similar to this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause Use FIELD as given in that link

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: is there no way to do where desc = "q1" as 1 or desc = "%q1%" as 2 and then do some kind of order on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to `UNION` the results and add a fake `OrderBy` field for each query.

```
SELECT   1 as OrderBy, *
FROM     users
WHERE    description = "query"
UNION ALL
SELECT   2 as OrderBy, *
FROM     users
WHERE    description = "%query%"
...
ORDER BY
         OrderBy
```

Comment: okay this is more what i wanted, i'll test it now but it looks good to me!

Comment: Or just use 1 query and do `order by (description = 'query') DESC`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE description = "query" or description = "%query%" or description IN ('q1','q2') or (description like '%q1%' or description like '%q2%') order by (description = "query") DESC, (description = "%query%") DESC, (description IN ('q1','q2')) DESC, (description like '%q1%' or description like '%q2%') DESC;` Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will produce the results you need

```
select * from users 
where description like "%query%" 
  or description like "%q1%" 
  or description like "%q2%"
```

Comment: yes but i want the query part to be all sorted ahead of the q1 and q2 parts