# SQL Script Ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My script has:

```
  select * from users where...
```

The where clause will have two parts, and they need to be ordered this way:

```
  1. where description = "query"

  2. where description = "%query%"
```

Is there some way to do where description= "query" as 1 or description = "%query%" as 2 and sort on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Ordering in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134509/sql-ordering-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT a.*,
       1 AS sort
  FROM USERS a
 WHERE a.description LIKE 'query'
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*,
       2 AS sort
  FROM USERS b
 WHERE b.description LIKE '%query%'
ORDER BY sort
```

Comment: +1 OMG, very much along my line of thought, so you must be right.  ;)  A useful tweak would be to change the second WHERE To include a `AND b.description <> 'query'` to prevent same user appearing twice in the results.

Comment: @Will A: I think Full Text Search (FTS) would be a better idea in the long run.