# How to change the default ordering of a query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I don't want any ordering to be applied to a query. So, I have a `QuerySet` follow as:

```
question_obj = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=[100,50,27,35,10,42,68]).order_by()
```

However, when I retrieve the results, they are always ordered by `questionID`. I iterate the `question_obj` and this is the result:

```
for obj in question_obj:
   obj.questionID
```

The result is displayed such as:

```
10L
27L
35L
42L
50L
68L
100L
```

Comment: Just in case: have you overlooked a `class Meta` ordering statement in the Model for Question?

Comment: I don't want to order the result. I just want to keep the objects in the same order as the list of primary keys.

Comment: @ThinhPhan if you want the order to follow the PKs, why not just `.order_by('pk')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the objects in the same order as the list of primary keys, then you could use [`in_bulk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) to create a dictionary keyed by pk. You can then use a list comprehension to generate the list of questions.

```
>>> pks = [100,50,27,35,10,42,68]
>>> questions_dict = Question.objects.in_bulk(pks)
>>> questions = [questions_dict[pk] for pk in pks]
>>> for question in questions:
        print question.pk
100
50
27
35
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the solution that I need to find

Answer (score 2):

If you want an unordered collection, use Python's Set object, documented here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

If you want the ordering to be the same as the list you're passing as the value for pk__in, you could try:

```
ids = [100,50,27,35,10,42,68]
questions = list(Question.objects.filter(pk__in=ids))
question_obj = sorted(questions, key=lambda x: ids.index(x.id))
```

EDIT: And because it's extremely unclear as to what you mean by 'unordered' in reference to a data structure that is by definition ordered: Random ordering can be accomplished through the following:

```
.order_by('?')
```

Comment: Nice tip with the `.order_by('?')`!!

Comment: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you're using.
I have just kept the same order as the list of primary keys

Answer (score 0):

Luke, use the Source, er, the Docs! Yeah, that's it!

[Django QuerySet API - order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: I think he wants to NOT order them by a particular field. Instead order them in the order they are suggested in the provided list

Comment: Dear Peter Rowell, I used the "Django QuerySet API - order_by()" in my statement but it is not effective.
question_obj = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=[100,50,27,35,10,42,68]).order_by()

It always return the order of questionID.

Comment: @ThinhPhan: I read "I don't want any ordering to be applied to a query" to mean literally that you wanted a random order. Given the answer you accepted as correct what you *meant* to say was "I want the objects returned in the order given by the IDs." Interestingly enough the `order_by('?')` operator silently does *nothing* when the query is given an explicit list of IDs (behavior which I consider to be a bug).

Answer (score 0):

You could do some raw SQL (with FIELD()) a lá:

[Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

which should allow you to retrieve them in the order suggested in the list.

To run custom SQL with the ORM:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly