# MySQL IN Operator result set order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In MySQL while using IN operator can we ask MySQL to return result-set(record-set) in same order as the IN set was?

explanation:
     Suppose we have a table 
    `items (item_id, item_name);`

and the query:

`select * from items where item_id in (1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8);`

can we have the result-set(record-set) where the records are in same order as IN operator set.
i.e `1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8 of record_id`s

This isn't the case; MySQL seems to optimise out the search and gives the default order(same as order of those records stored on File-system).

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use MySQL's `field` function in your ORDER BY clause:

```
select *
from items
where item_id in (1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8)
order by field(item_id, 1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8)
```

The [`field` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

> `FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)`
>
> Returns the index (position) of *str* in the *str1*, *str2*, *str3*, ... list. Returns 0 if *str* is not found.
>
> If all arguments to `FIELD()` are strings, all arguments are compared as strings. If all arguments are numbers, they are compared as numbers. Otherwise, the arguments are compared as double.