# MySql fetchin in order by IN clause

Tags: php, sql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

I know we can fetch all the rows in mysql in php by using the array as

```
$ids=array(14,23,2,41,33)

select * from table_name where id IN ($ids);
```

now the issue is that i want the rows to be fetched in the order of the elements i.e.

first the row with id 14 should be taken from row, then 23, then 2.. what currently fetches the data is in order -> first row with id 2, then with 14, then with 23 ....

and i "CANNOT" run a loop, cause the array is about 200 element long, cannot query the server with 200 at same instance. any ideas..?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,210905,210918#msg-210918 See if this works for you

Comment: thanks.. nice idea.. bdw.. got another method.. FIND_IN_SET .. works great..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ids = array( 14,23,2,41,33);
$sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM table_name
        WHERE id IN ( ' . implode( ',', $ids) . ' )
        ORDER BY FIELD( id, ' . implode( ', ', $ids) . ')';
```

Comment: THANKS..! it works..! and as i mentioned in the comment find-in_set works too.. but now havin trouble putin it up at cakePHP.. :(