# Get all records with an ID, but the first records should match another condition also

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am fetching all stations which belong to a station group from my database. `SELECT * FROM stations WHERE station_group_id = 1`.

Now, from all the fetched results, I want certain ones to appear first (e.g. the stations which have line_id = 2 to appear first). For example, if this is my `stations` table:

```
id | station_group_id | line_id
-------------------------------
1  |                1 |       1
2  |                1 |       2
3  |                1 |       3
```

I would like the output to be:

```
id | station_group_id | line_id
-------------------------------
1  |                1 |       2
2  |                1 |       1
3  |                1 |       3
```

So that `line_id = 2` is the first record in the output.

I thought about using `ORDER BY`, but it isn't quite an order issue, it is more a "preference" one.

So, is it possible to place some records on top of the output, based on a condition, preferably in one query? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

Comment: It is not quite a duplicate. I need to order by letting only certain records on top of the output, not using the order from a previous query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below:

```
SELECT * FROM stations 
WHERE station_group_id = 1 
ORDER BY if(line_id in('2','X','Y','Z'),0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM stations WHERE station_group_id = 1 and line_id = 2
union 
SELECT * FROM stations WHERE station_group_id = 1 and 
         line_id != 2 order by line_id asc
```

Comment: I thought about unions, but I'll go for the other answer. Vote up for a useful answer, though.

Comment: or, you can assign line_id = 2 to the record with id=1 and vice versa. then you can run a simple select with "order by". ;)

Comment: Id's and number of records to move on top are random, so I wanted something cleaner :)

Comment: if you want a more generalized solution you should add a column to the table called "display_order".

Comment: And what will be the use of it? I'll still have to iterate all over the table to populate this field based on the current query. And, as I said, the order is dynamic, so it changes from one query to another, so the previous order will be useless in the current query.

Comment: @linkyndy sorry - I didn't notice that you said you wanted to sort it dynamically. how will you know, during run time, to use a condition like: "ORDER BY if(line_id in('2','X','Y','Z'),0,1)" - the "2" is hardcoded, no ?

Comment: I am using an array with the desired `line_id`s in that `if()` clause.

Comment: An array - meaning hardcoded solution (it's not "really" dynamic). If it's going to stay like this forever then I guess that it's totally fine, but if the values in this array might change in the future - then you'll need to test+deploy code changes every time instead of changing fields in a table (display_id).

Comment: Why should an array necessarily be hardcoded? It is generated upon data from the current query. Anyway, my implementation of the accepted answer works fine and I also voted up your answer because it is useful :)

Comment: @linkyndy - it's really not about the upvote or about the "accept". You're missing the point: all I'm saying is that if you know in advance the values then it's not dynamic and you can build a generic solution that will not require code-changes even if values will change in the future.

Comment: Before querying my database, I have an array with the line_ids which should be moved on top of the results. That is the array I use in the if() clause and returns the desired result set. It's least I can do for it to work, adding and modifying an extra field in the table for each query requires more work to be done. I hope I made my point clear (and also that understood yours).

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, it is actually a preference, so you should either model it as an extra field on the table (e.g. ordinal, or order, or preferredOrder), or you keep sorting by line_id, and do the "special sort" in code. (find element with id=2, move to top)

Comment: I wanted to do this within a query, so as not to parse the results again afterwards.