# Is there a way to order the results of a query with a non standard order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My site allows users to change the order in which categories and what categories are displayed, and it stores that order as an array in the db. so I have:

```
@categories = Category.where("id IN (?)", current_user.order)
```

the problem is order is something like [2,4,3,6,1] and then @categories has order [1,2,3,4,6]. 
I want to order the @categories so it matches the order.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I ended up going with the solution listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Store user preferences in a separate table and then JOIN userOrderTable with @categories

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to create an empty array and iterate over the Categories:

```
@categories = []
current_user.order.each do |category_id|
 @categories << Category.find(category_id)
end
```