# Yii dataProvider the data order given by an array

Tags: php, yii, dataprovider

I've searched a lot about that and didn't got the answer so far. Here's the problem:
I'm creating CDbCriteria object to get proper data:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('id_post', $arrayContents);
```

where `$arrayContents` is an array consisting of the following elements:

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 14 [3] => 15 )
```

Those are the `id_posts` I want to present using dataProvider, but only in that specific order. Further i create dataProvider this way:

```
$dataProviderPosts = new CActiveDataProvider('Posts',array(
            'criteria'   => $criteria,
            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>20,
            ),
    ));
```

The order of displayed `id_posts` is: 10, 14, 15, 16. Not the one that i wanted.
I've also tried creating dataProvider like that:

```
$dataProviderPosts = new CActiveDataProvider('Posts',array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                    'defaultOrder'=>array('id_post'=>$arrayContents),
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>20,
            ),
    ));
```

But it only did displaying it in that order: 16, 15, 14, 10, so just backward, so not what I wanted, because I want to display it in order: 10, 16, 14, 15 just like numbers in `$arrayContents`.

Comment: well, it is not acually a Yii problem, but db, here is question about sorting by in clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause However i dont know how to apply it to Yii dataprovider.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. That gave me some new ideas, but none of them worked so far.

Comment: Add another field in table `priority`. Set priority in order to display the data according to your choice. Simple! Maybe not a solution for your answer, but a random idea. This might can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CActiveDataProvider wont do what you need. The order it provides is just the plain SQL order, it has to be computed as a combination of columns ASC or DESC.

The order you want looks like an arbitrary order of ids. I guess you don't have other columns like 'position' or so in your model, so you'll have to sort your data yourself.

I didn't try but after the API, you may use the **getData()** / **setData()** methods in order to extract data, sort it and set it back in your provider.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Since i posted it I didn't had much time, but after all it took me a while after I understand how those getData() and setData() works. For those, who could be interested in implementing that's sort of how I did it:

Comment: `$arrayContents2 = $dataProviderPosts->getData();
  $arrayContents3 = $dataProviderPosts->getData();
  $arrayContents4 = $arrayPhraseInContents;
  sort($arrayContents4);
  $number = count($arrayContents);
  for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++)
  {
   $key = array_search($arrayPhraseInContents4[$i], $arrayPhraseInContents);
   $arrayPhraseInContents2[$key]=$arrayPhraseInContents3[$i];
  }
   
  $dataProviderPosts->setData($arrayContents2);`