# How to make Elastica Query sorting work?

Tags: elastica

I'm trying to get search results sorted, but I just get the unsorted results with the following code (in this example I query for all results):

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query();
$query->setSort(array('id' => array('order' => 'desc')));
$resultSet = $type->search($query); // where $type is an elastica type object
$results = $resultSet->getResults();
```

For reference, I'm using the FOSElasticaBundle with a Symfony2 project (using `$type = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.index.website.myType');`), but that should not make a difference.

If I make the query directly on the browser with `http://localhost:9200/website/myType/_search?sort=id:desc&pretty=true`, I get the results correctly sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the code given in the question is correct, and it does return the correctly sorted results.

The problem I was having was unrelated to Elastica and the code given in the question.

Turns out that the results I was retuning in my HTML were unsorted because I was not returning my Elastica Query results but the corresponding objects from my SQL database that were obtained from a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
WHERE id IN([ids from Elastica results in order])
```

The above SQL query does not return results in the order of the ids given in the "IN" clause, so it was necessary to re-order the SQL results to match the order of my ElasticSearch results (which I did with foreach statements). If I had been using MySQL I could have used [`ORDER BY FIELD(id, \[ids in order\])`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/396771/1362009) to get SQL results in the same order as the ids provided in the IN clause.