# Using IN and ordering?

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE id IN (300, 400, 100)
```

But it always orders the articles the same, by id.

So I would get out for the above:

```
id
100
300
400
```

Is there a way to get the results out in the order that they were requested in the IN statement? eg.

```
id
300
400
100
```

Comment: Unless you provide an `ORDER BY` clause, result *sets* from an SQL select are by definition unordered

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause?rq=1

Answer (score 12):

You can try something like this. Use the [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

```
SELECT * FROM article 
WHERE id IN (300, 400, 100) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 300, 400, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the values you want into a temporary table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TempT (sortOrder int,
                    id int);

INSERT INTO TempT (sortOrder, id) VALUES
(1, 300),(2, 400),(3, 100);
```

And then just join to the table like so:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM article a
INNER JOIN TempT t ON a.id = t.id
ORDER BY t.sortOrder;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/440ec/4/0) example.  This works well if you have a lot of values you need to incorporate in the `IN` statement.