# Doctrine2 custom records order

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have simple query to get all pictures from database:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

And I have array of ID's, which represents how they should be arranged in result array. How can I tell doctrine, to return these pictures in that specific order? For example, my "order array" is [3, 5, 9, 1, 10] and I want to get results in that particular order.

Comment: As pointed by @JasonRoman, you must accept the answer that solves your problem, in order to people with the same problem can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  If you're using postgresql you can try one of the raw queries here: [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list) .  If you're using mysql you can try the suggestions here: [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

If you instead want to do it through straight Doctrine you could create a generic mapper function that orders the results.  For very large result sets you may hit performance issues since you have O(n^2).  But it's a little simpler than trying to make your own custom Doctrine function to handle it, relying on database implementation.

Say your query returns 5 results with the following ids: (95, 4, 1, 33, 35).  Now say you want them returned as (1, 35, 4, 33, 95):

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Picture')->findBy(/*some criteria*/);

$orderFunction = function($id) use ($entities)
{
    foreach ($entities as $entity)
    {
        if ($entity->getId() == $id) {
            return $entity;
        }
    }
};

$orderAs = array(1, 35, 4, 33, 95);
$orderedEntities = array_map($orderFunction, $orderAs);
```

Now your `$orderedEntities` array will be in the order you specified.

Comment: Thank you! This one fits my needs perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this fits your needs please accept my answer as the correct one so others can see that as well.