# Sequelize - Query with multipleID and not order

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have an array of two ids:

```
placeids = [22,14]
```

Then I have this query:

```
models.Places.findAll({
            where: {
                id: {in: [ placeids ]}
            }

    }).then(function (places) {
        response(places).code(200);
    }, function (rejectedPromiseError) {
        response(rejectedPromiseError).code(401);
    });
```

I want the result to return exact records, the way I have requested them, in my case 22 and then 14.

Sequelize return them, but it orders them in descending. So in my case it returns 14 and 22.

How can I address this?

Comment: I doubt Sequelize orders them, it's the SQL database that does so. Being able to influence that order depends on whether or not the database supports such a thing (MySQL does, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/396771/893780)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `sequelize` an `order` parameter:

```
models.Places.findAll({
    where: {
        id: {in: [placeids]}
    },
    order: 'id DESC'
});
```

Or, you can do the ordering manually:

```
.then(function (places) {
    places.sort(function (x, y) {
        return placeids.indexOf(x.id) > placeids.indexOf(y.id)
    });
    return places;
});
```