# JPA Criteria Query, ordering the result using a list of ordered ids

Tags: sql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Lets say I have an "Item" table in my database and an "Item" entity object in my Java code JPA mapping.

And I am given a sorted list of "Item" ids, for which I want to retrieve the actual "Items" from the database, with the same ordering as in the given list.

Now I can't really just retrieve the items first and then order them because I only want to retrieve a small range of these items from the database after the ordering.

Is this possible to do? I know that there are ways of doing this using pure SQL, e.g.

[Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

[ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list)

Answer (score 0):

I usually call this technique ["sort indirection"](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-implement-sort-indirection-in-sql/), where you sort a data set according to another pre-sorted data set. In SQL, you could use the `FIELD()` function in MySQL (as per your linked questions), or in more standard SQL, you'd use something like:

```sql
ORDER BY 
  CASE value WHEN 3 THEN 1
             WHEN 5 THEN 2
             WHEN 1 THEN 3
                    ELSE 4 END,
  secondary_criteria
```

This would produce values ordered as `[3, 5, 1, ...]`

Now, `CASE` is something you can do with the criteria API as well:

```java
cb.selectCase()
  .when(..., ...)
  .when(..., ...)
  .when(..., ...)
  .otherwise(...)
```